# find experience and display users with it

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I have a textbox where user enters some number, for example, 6. And I have a datagridview based on my class which contains name, employment date and position. I need to show employees who is working on this company for 6 years or more. And when user enters a new number, show the new list of employees who is working for that period of time. It is necessary to subtract the date of employment from today's date and if this number is equal to or higher than the one entered in the textbox, then display employees who have such work experience in this company. I already did something similar with name, here is code of that:

```
var text = textBox4.Text;
var result = workers.MyList.Where(m => m._Name == text).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

For adding new employees I used:

```
workers.Add(new employee(textBox1.Text, dateTimePicker1.Value, textBox2.Text));
var data = workers.MyList.Select(bring => new
{
    Name = bring._Name,
    Date = bring._Date,
    Position = bring._Position,
}).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

Comment: Do you have any property for `DateOfJoining` or giving value of experience in `worker.MyList`? Show us actual code which is used for experience

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I added to the post the way I add new employees

Comment: is your `Date` property contains joining date?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar yes, it's datatime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Date` property is employees joining date with type `DateTime`, then you can try below code,

```
if(int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out int exp))
{
   //Get difference between today's year and  Date year
   dataGridView1.DataSource = data
                .Where(x => (DateTime.Today.Year - x.Date.Year) >= exp)  
                .ToList(); //Convert to list
}
else
   MessageBox.Show("Invalid experiece enter a number", "Invalid experience", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Comment: I need to get information about the year from textbox, and yes, my date's type is DateTime.

Comment: I tried like this, It didn't work. private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int exp = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            var resultt =  workers.MyList.Where(x => (x._Date.Year - DateTime.Now.Year) >= exp)
                .ToList(); //Convert to list
            dataGridView1.DataSource = resultt;
        }

Comment: It worked, I just switched x.Date.Year and today's day. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, `DateOfJoining` is always less than `Today's` date. I fixed it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me.

```
var exp = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
var res=  workers.MyList.Where(x => (DateTime.Now.Year - x._Date.Year) >= exp)
            .ToList(); //Convert to list
dataGridView1.DataSource = res;
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an error if the textbox contains non-integer value, check my answer I used `int.TryParse()`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar yep, it worked too, but I changed it a bit. if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out int exp))
            {
                var resultt = workers.MyList.Where(x => (DateTime.Now.Year - x._Date.Year) >= exp).ToList(); ;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = resultt;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid experiece enter a number", "Invalid experience", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }